# Getting id of an element in jQuery using a function

Tags: jquery

I have a simple code with two buttons in a div container. I want to get the id of a button using a function.

**Problem**: Can someone please explain why clicking on Button1 doesn't alert `myButton1`? How can I solve this issue?

**Code**:

```
<html>
<body>
    <style type="text/CSS">
        #mydiv{
            border: 1px dashed blue;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <input type="button" id="myButton1" value="Button1"></input>
        <input type="button" id="myButton2" value="Button2"></input>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**code.js** :

```
myfunction = function(e){
    alert(this.id);
    e.stopPropagation();
    }

$('#myDiv').click(function(){
            alert($('#myDiv').attr('id'));
        });

$('#myButton1').click("myfunction()");

$('#myButton2').click(function(e){
            alert(this.id);
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) is supposed to get `Function`, not `String` as parameter.

It should be:

```
$('#myButton1').click(myfunction);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dq8bsd42/).

Comment: This is a perfect  solution, short and simple. I can atleast give +1 to all. :)

Comment: @pss yes, it will be fair enough :)

Comment: Doesn't meet the OP's requirement to "explain why clicking on Button1 doesn't alert myButton1?"

Comment: @pss your question states that you want to get the ID of the button within `myfunction`... but this doesn't answer the question... at all.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I agree that I don't provide explanation as Moob mentioned, but I don't understand what you are against of...

Comment: @JamesDonnelly the question was **why clicking on Button1 doesn't alert myButton1?**  and **How can I solve this issue?**

Comment: @all, the fact that the OP accepted the answer is surely enough of a judgement as far as the OP is concerned.  Thankfully for the rest of the viewers who come here, there are various answers that go into more depth and allow the intrigued reader to inform themselves further.

Comment: @all Well I think may be my question was bit unclear for some users. But this answer is doing exactly what I wanted and stated in my question. I just wanted a function/method that will return the id of Button1 when it uses/calls this function/method. I don't see anythong wrong with this answer. Moob's answer is also great but he/she has implemented this method for all the other elements too, that I never asked for in my question. Moob has already explained the answer very well. I can't accept TWO answers so I generally gave +1 to all the contributors. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`$('#myButton1').click(function(){myfunction(this)});`

```
myfunction = function(e){
    alert(e.target.id);
    e.stopPropagation();
    }
```

Comment: What about removing unnecessary `""`?

Comment: So it means I still have to define a function in the click() of myButton1 which will in turn call my myFunction()

Comment: @pss yes as otherwise it get's interpreted straight away if it is not in an "immediately Invoked Function Expression" http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: @pss see @moob's answer, if you change the function call to `myfunction()` it will immediately interpret.  Hence you can either wrap is in an IIFE or call it without the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Your `#myButton2` example is accurate. You need to use `this.id` to get the ID of the element which the event has been fired on:

```
$('#myDiv').click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

However this isn't clicking on the button, this is clicking on the `#myDiv` element as a whole.

If you want one event to handle the click on all your buttons, you can use:

```
$('#myDiv').find('input[type="button"]').click(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
$('#myButton1').click(function(){
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click on `myButton1` the JS is unable to dispatch the event and throws `TypeError: undefined is not a function` because you are calling it incorrectly. Your browser may however register the click on the parent `#myDiv` hence alerting its id rather than the one you're expecting.

You were almost bang-on with your own code. Since you're passing `myfunction` as an argument of the click function it shouldn't have the brackets or speechmarks.

E.G:

```
myfunction = function(e){
    alert(this.id);
    e.stopPropagation();
}

$('#myDiv, #myButton1, #myButton2').click(myfunction);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asmr0305/1/

Comment: This is almost the same. But why it didn't work in my case? If I click button1 it alerts myDiv instead of myButton1.

Comment: @ρss it alerts "myButton1" for me in this fiddle.

Comment: @Regent do you mean the code I provided in the question is alerting myButton1 for you?

Comment: Yes, that will work since he is using click(myfuncion) and I did the wrong way.